# JavaScript VS Perl Script

Tags: javascript, perl, report

I'm currently doing some research for a report that surveys two scripting languages. Mine is on JavaScript and Perl Script
I wanted to know if there is any 'not so well known' differences between these two.
A some known onee being that they both process text events differently and that JavaScript is Client Side and Perl is Server Side.

Comment: The languages themselves have nothing in common.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: _"JavaScript is Client Side"_ - Except when it isn't. _"Perl is Server Side"_ - Except when it isn't.

Comment: @SLaks: actually, they have a lot in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the wikipedia pages for each language. Then grab some reference books on each (the Camel book for Perl, obviously).

Areas to consider might include:

- Approach to types
- Namespacing / variable scoping
- Module/Class/Package inclusion mechanisms
- argument passing semantics
- return value contexts (search for scalar/list context wrt perl)
- Multi-processing/multi-threading support/approaches
- Unicode support
- Standard libraries
- Range of additional libraries
- Installation methods for additional libraries
- Common environments/platforms
- Supported environments/platforms
- History of each

There you go. If you wrote a few pages on each of those you've got a small book. A paragraph on each should be more than enough for a report.